# Submultiplicativity stronger than triangle inequality?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I would like to ask a question about matrix norm.

Is the submiltiplicativity property always stronger than the triangle inequality? So, if i prove for a matrix norm that it's submultiplicative, i don't need to show that the triangle inequality holds too?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have a matrix norm, you already know it satisfies the triangle inequality. Do you mean if you have a function satisfying the other two and also being submultiplicative?

Comment: Yes, i meant exactly this. I have to prove that something is a matrix norm. It satisfies the first two properties, but i also see that it's submultiplicative. Does the submultiplicativity imply the triangly inequality?

Comment: Some people include the submultiplicativity in the definition of a matrix norm but still have the triangle inequality also there, so I guess this implication doesn't hold. I don't know and can't find a counterexample at least right away, though. Interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

The map $A \mapsto |\det A|^{1/n}$ satisfies all the desired property as a counter-example except for the nondegeneracy. So we perturb this map in the following way:

Let $\| \cdot \|$ be any submultiplicative matrix norm on $M_{n\times n}$, and define

$$ \| A \|' = \| A \| + t |\det A|^{1/n},$$

where $t \geq 1$ is a constant to be chosen later. Then

1. $\| A \|' \geq 0$ with equality holds if and only if $A = O$.
2. $\| \alpha A \|' = |\alpha| \| A \|'$.
3. Using $t \leq t^{2}$, we get
   \begin{align*}
   \| AB \|'
   &= \|AB\| + t |\det A|^{1/n} |\det B|^{1/n} \\
   &\leq \|A\|\|B\| + t^{2} |\det A|^{1/n} |\det B|^{1/n} \\
   &\leq ( \|A\| + t |\det A|^{1/n}) ( \|B\| + t |\det B|^{1/n})
    = \|A\|' \|B\|'.
   \end{align*}

But if we choose two singular $A, B$ that add up to $I_{n}$, then

$$ \|I\| + t = \| I \|' = \| A+B \|'$$

while

$$ \|A\|' + \|B\|' = \|A\| + \|B\|. $$

Now choose $t$ sufficiently large so that $\| I \| + t > \| A \| + \| B \|$. This invalidates the triangle inequality.